# Maven Build Failure for artifact ID jira-rest-java-client-app

Tags: java, maven, jira-rest-api, jira-integration

The below dependency was already existing in our organization repository and it was removed for some reasons

Later I changed the repository as below and updated it with new repository  which has this dependency 5.2.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-app</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The repository updated as below

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>maven_dev</name>
        <url>https://artifactory.organization.site/artifactory/maven_dev</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

When I build project after these changes am getting the below error

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project testngframeworkLibrary:PETERTESTNG:jar:3.16: Failed to collect dependencies at com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-app:jar:5.2.0: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-app:jar:5.2.0: Failure to find com.atlassian.platform:platform:pom:3.1.7 in https://artifactory.organization.site/artifactory/maven_dev was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of org-maven_dev has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that dependency com.atlassian.platform:platform:pom:3.1.7 cannot be found for some reason. What I typically do in these situations is manually go to the Artifactory repository and confirm the artifact exists. If it does then you know you either have a pom entry error or a corrupted local artifact. Then you can address as needed. For future reference, whenever you get these Maven build errors, drop the error into your web browser search function, remove the references to the specific artifact name/group/version and run a search. You should get a lot of hits.

Comment: Checked that com.atlassian.platform:platform:pom:3.1.7 not exist in the maven_dev repo. but does this exist in the maven repo? so i can request my tem to add this into maven_dev